# Deleting files from a folder - android

Tags: java, android

I have a folder which contains some files that I want to deleted after processing them. The files have the extension `.FIR` After some googling I found a recursive method that I modified a bit:

```
void delete(File f) throws IOException {
      if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : f.listFiles())
            if(f.listFiles().toString().contains(".FIR"))
                delete(c);
      }
      if (!f.delete())
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to delete file: " + f);
    }
```

This function will throw an IOException telling me:

```
07-31 11:02:31.885: E/DELETE:(5694): Failed to delete file: /mnt/sdcard/ExtractedFiles
```

The folder has been set to `RW` operations. And in my manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I couldn't find another permission that sounded something like `MODIFY_FILES`

Any ideas?

Comment: why `if(f.listFiles).toString().contains...`. You have to check c extension right? Not if your current folder has some .FIR file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
void delete(File f) throws IOException {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : f.listFiles()) {
            delete(c);
        }
    } else if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("FIR")) {
        if (!f.delete()) {
            new FileNotFoundException("Failed to delete file: " + f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the logic behind FIR?

Answer (score 4):

Better use `temp` files....

`File f = File.createTempFile("pattern", ".suffix");`

Once the application is closed, the **temp files are first closed then deleted.**

See this link for more details:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/create-temp-file.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here:

```
if(f.listFiles().toString().contains(".FIR"))
```

change this to:

```
if(c.getName().contains(".FIR"))
```

And make sure your directory contains files with extension **.FIR** only, otherwise (if any other extension files are available) it will still fail to delete a non-empty directory

---

Otherwise use the following method to get it done:

```
private static boolean delete(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = delete(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return (dir.getName().contains(".FIR"))? dir.delete() : false;
}
```

Comment: The exception will *not** be thrown if I do so, but the files in the directory will not be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

check this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>`

Comment: The same exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

i was using this code and it;s working:

```
 String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 File file = new File(path) ;       
  File list[] = file.listFiles();
    for(File f:list)
      {
     name =  file.getName();
    filestv.setText(f.getName());
    //add new files name in the list
   //  delete.setText(name );


      }  


}
```

and you can follow the complete [tutorials](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/06/delete-latest-file-from-any-specific.html)